# Can't check what button is pressed in pynput

Tags: python, key, pynput

I have problem with Keys in pynput

on_press function should check if button pressed i 'h' but it gives error

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    if key == Key.h:
        print('done')


def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: the error is created by the `if key == Key.h:` statement inside the `on_press` function.  When i comment this out, it works !!

Comment: yep ik, i try to solve this, to check if pressed button is ... ex. 'h'

Answer (score 1):

the error is created by the `if key == Key.h:` statement inside the `on_press` function. When i comment this out, **it works without error**.

So this works:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    # if key == Key.h:    # <-- cause the error
    #     print('done')  # <-- cause the error


def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

returns (when i press various buttons etc):

```
'h'
'h' release
Key.alt_l
Key.tab
Key.alt_l release
Key.tab release
Key.alt_l
Key.tab
Key.alt_l release
```

It looks like *the examples* use a `try-except` block for the equivalent `on_press` function that you have created.

Here is the link to how it works:  https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

When i replace the function with this is performs well:

```py
def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    try:
        if key == Key.h:
            print('done')
    except:
        print('something else')
```

and i get this:

```
'h'
something else
'h' release
'i'
something else
'i' release
Key.alt_l
something else
Key.tab
something else
Key.alt_l release
Key.tab release
Key.alt_l
```

You can see that the `exception` needs to be handled (many time) from the above, which is why the code in the question was broken.

Answer (score 0):

your way to solve this problem doesn't work or maybe it's mine misunderstanding. When i tried to comment every print, to only print 'done' after checking if pressed key is 'h' it doesn't work

```
def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key == Key.h:
            print('done')
    except:
        return


def on_release(key):
    #print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
```

Comment: the result i posted above completely works. i even posted the output and told you where the error was (to replace the `on_press` function).  Which part does not work.

Comment: so tell me why it didn't print 'done' after you press 'h'?

Comment: the reason why is because quite often the except is triggerred.  You can identify when this is the case by putting print statements into both the `try` part and the `except` part.

Comment: i noticed that if i press `h` when the `vs code` is open, then the `try` block is executed (so 'done' is printed) but when i press `h` over the web browser the `except` block is executed.   So you need to look into that, but it works...

Comment: well i will try to figure it out thank you bro